# Write an own layer with trainable parameters in Tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I want to write an easy, own *Exponentiation* layer in Tensorflow 2. It should take n inputs [x_1, ..., x_n] and output some powers [x_1^e_1, ..., x_n^e_n], where e_1, ..., e_n are trainable parameters.

For example, this Exponentiation layer together with a Dense layer (with output dimension 1) could learn any function of the form a_1*x_1^e_1+...+a_n*x_n^e_n, which is a simple extension of normal, linear regression.

However, I have no luck with getting t to work. So far, I have written the following:

```
import tensorflow as tf

class Exponent(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.exp = self.add_weight(name='Exponent', shape=input_shape, initializer=tf.constant_initializer(value=1.), trainable=True)
        super().build(input_shape)
        
    def call(self, inputs, training=False):
        return tf.math.pow(inputs, self.exp)
```

I can instantiate an object of this class, and everything works fine.

```
e = Exponent()
e.build(input_shape=(2,))
e([[1., 2.]]) # works fine
```

If I try to embed it in a model, it throws an error when trying to predict (or also fit):

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    Exponent(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
])

model.compile(
    loss='mse',
    optimizer='sgd'
)

model.predict([[1., 2., 3.]])
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-401-2ea9d74ffa37> in <module>
      9 )
     10 
---> 11 model.predict([[1., 2., 3.]])

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    128       raise ValueError('{} is not supported in multi-worker mode.'.format(
    129           method.__name__))
--> 130     return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    131 
    132   return tf_decorator.make_decorator(

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in predict(self, x, batch_size, verbose, steps, callbacks, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1597           for step in data_handler.steps():
   1598             callbacks.on_predict_batch_begin(step)
-> 1599             tmp_batch_outputs = predict_function(iterator)
   1600             if data_handler.should_sync:
   1601               context.async_wait()

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    778       else:
    779         compiler = "nonXla"
--> 780         result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    781 
    782       new_tracing_count = self._get_tracing_count()

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    821       # This is the first call of __call__, so we have to initialize.
    822       initializers = []
--> 823       self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
    824     finally:
    825       # At this point we know that the initialization is complete (or less

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in _initialize(self, args, kwds, add_initializers_to)
    695     self._concrete_stateful_fn = (
    696         self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 697             *args, **kwds))
    698 
    699     def invalid_creator_scope(*unused_args, **unused_kwds):

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2853       args, kwargs = None, None
   2854     with self._lock:
-> 2855       graph_function, _, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   2856     return graph_function
   2857 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   3211 
   3212       self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)
-> 3213       graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
   3214       self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] = graph_function
   3215       return graph_function, args, kwargs

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
   3073             arg_names=arg_names,
   3074             override_flat_arg_shapes=override_flat_arg_shapes,
-> 3075             capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
   3076         self._function_attributes,
   3077         function_spec=self.function_spec,

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes)
    984         _, original_func = tf_decorator.unwrap(python_func)
    985 
--> 986       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
    987 
    988       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
    598         # __wrapped__ allows AutoGraph to swap in a converted function. We give
    599         # the function a weak reference to itself to avoid a reference cycle.
--> 600         return weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
    601     weak_wrapped_fn = weakref.ref(wrapped_fn)
    602 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    971           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    972             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 973               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    974             else:
    975               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    C:\Users\robkuble\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:1462 predict_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    C:\Users\robkuble\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:1452 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    C:\Users\robkuble\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:1211 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    C:\Users\robkuble\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2585 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    C:\Users\robkuble\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2945 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    C:\Users\robkuble\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:1445 run_step  **
        outputs = model.predict_step(data)
    C:\Users\robkuble\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:1418 predict_step
        return self(x, training=False)
    C:\Users\robkuble\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py:985 __call__
        outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    C:\Users\robkuble\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\sequential.py:386 call
        outputs = layer(inputs, **kwargs)
    C:\Users\robkuble\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py:982 __call__
        self._maybe_build(inputs)
    C:\Users\robkuble\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py:2643 _maybe_build
        self.build(input_shapes)  # pylint:disable=not-callable
    <ipython-input-357-5a69bae7457e>:8 build
        self.exp = self.add_weight(name='Exponent', shape=input_shape, initializer=tf.constant_initializer(value=2.), trainable=True)
    C:\Users\robkuble\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py:614 add_weight
        caching_device=caching_device)
    C:\Users\robkuble\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\tracking\base.py:750 _add_variable_with_custom_getter
        **kwargs_for_getter)
    C:\Users\robkuble\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer_utils.py:145 make_variable
        shape=variable_shape if variable_shape else None)
    C:\Users\robkuble\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variables.py:260 __call__
        return cls._variable_v1_call(*args, **kwargs)
    C:\Users\robkuble\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variables.py:221 _variable_v1_call
        shape=shape)
    C:\Users\robkuble\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variables.py:67 getter
        return captured_getter(captured_previous, **kwargs)
    C:\Users\robkuble\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2857 creator
        return next_creator(**kwargs)
    C:\Users\robkuble\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variables.py:67 getter
        return captured_getter(captured_previous, **kwargs)
    C:\Users\robkuble\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2857 creator
        return next_creator(**kwargs)
    C:\Users\robkuble\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variables.py:67 getter
        return captured_getter(captured_previous, **kwargs)
    C:\Users\robkuble\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2857 creator
        return next_creator(**kwargs)
    C:\Users\robkuble\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variables.py:67 getter
        return captured_getter(captured_previous, **kwargs)
    C:\Users\robkuble\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py:685 variable_capturing_scope
        lifted_initializer_graph=lifted_initializer_graph, **kwds)
    C:\Users\robkuble\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variables.py:264 __call__
        return super(VariableMetaclass, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
    C:\Users\robkuble\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py:226 __init__
        initial_value() if init_from_fn else initial_value,
    C:\Users\robkuble\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\init_ops_v2.py:263 __call__
        self.value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape)
    C:\Users\robkuble\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py:264 constant
        allow_broadcast=True)
    C:\Users\robkuble\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py:275 _constant_impl
        return _constant_eager_impl(ctx, value, dtype, shape, verify_shape)
    C:\Users\robkuble\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py:321 _constant_eager_impl
        return _eager_fill(shape.as_list(), t, ctx)
    C:\Users\robkuble\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py:54 _eager_fill
        dims = convert_to_eager_tensor(dims, ctx, dtypes.int32)
    C:\Users\robkuble\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py:98 convert_to_eager_tensor
        return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)

    ValueError: Attempt to convert a value (None) with an unsupported type (<class 'NoneType'>) to a Tensor.
```

Do you see, why there is a none type appearing somewhere? Thank you very much!

Best
Robert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first dimension in the `input_shape` argument of the `build` method corresponds to the batch size, which typically is None (this means that the network can work with batches of any size). For example, when calling `model.predict([[1., 2., 3.]])` the `input_shape` will be `(None, 3)`.

This means you need to change your implementation of the `build` method slightly to use `input_shape[-1]` instead of `input_shape`

```py
...

  def build(self, input_shape):
    self.exp = self.add_weight(name='Exponent', shape=input_shape[-1], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(value=1.), trainable=True)
    super().build(input_shape)
```